# How to get over my Valid Application from being repeatedly Blocked by Firewall

Tags: sockets, delphi, firewall

I use Delphi. I have a backup application which has to run constantly on my customers machines. Communicaton is done via TCP/IP Sockets & data is transferred via FTP.
My problem is that sometimes when the customer upgrades his AntiVirus or I send a upgrade the Firewall blocks my Application even though setup was done via elevated rights. How do I overcome this. I had thought running my communication portion from a Windows Service Application would solve the matter.

Comment: Firewalls block services just as easily as normal apps. The solution is to configure the firewall to allow your app to pass through. You can't really bypass that step in the customer's security.

Comment: To add to @RemyLebeau comment: this should be handled at install time by adding a firewall rule that allows your application (with consent by user of course).

Comment: >> "with consent by user of course" - Absolutely, as the user himself does the setup.  I am asking this because during Setup elevation question is asked. Is it something to do with Certification ? Why do firewalls not block programs like interbase and so many others ?

Comment: On a side note, don't use FTP if you don't really have to. Antiviruses and firewalls hate FTP. When we distributed our software and added support for downloading updates via FTP (not my decision), some peoples' AV literally deleted our software. We had to roll back and use HTTP instead.

Comment: I tried out HTTP Server (ICS had ready sample). Same issue gets blocked by Windows Firewall.